# Android studio, /storage/emulated/0 not exist

Tags: java, android

I tried to follow the example from a Youtuber named [Pixel_95](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3pyyQbwLko) about read and write file. It uses permission to write to external device.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then

```
public String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/readWriteTutorial";
```

This creates a path as "/storage/emulated/0/readWriteTutorial". In onCreate(). I put

```
File dir = new File(path);
dir.mkdirs();
```

However, there is no such a folder on my device. There is no /storage/emulated anywhere using the File Manager app from my Samsung S7. So when it tries to run:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

in a Save() method. Exception is caught.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.jiajunyang.readwrite, PID: 1170
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213) 
                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileOutputStream.close()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.jiajunyang.readwrite.MainActivity.Save(MainActivity.java:161)
                                                                                    at com.example.jiajunyang.readwrite.MainActivity.onSaveClicked(MainActivity.java:111)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213) 
                                                                                    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074) 
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Mainly this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.FileOutputStream.close()' on a null object reference
```

So what is the solution to this? I couldn't seems to get a correct path to make a directory. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)` to get the list of all the external path you can use on your phone and check if "storage/emulated/0" appears.

Comment: What is the variable file? Any stacktrace when initializing fos?

Comment: Also on Marshmallow+ devices, declaring manifest permission alone won't be enough. You have to request few permissions during runtime(includes storage) 

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @SPraveenKumar, thanks. I actually also have . a request Permission. But it seems to be the same.

Comment: @Zelig63, can you be a bit more specific on how to use this? Thanks. Do you mean replacing Environment.getExternalStoraggeDirectory() with this?

Comment: If the FileOutputStream is null, there would be an exception thrown by it's constructor right? Check the logs for it.

Comment: No. This will only give you which external directory exist on your device, and you will then be able to check if "storage/emulated/0" appears in the list.

Comment: @Zelig63. Thank you! You are right. I should use getExternalFilesDirs(null) instead of getExternalStorageDirectory(). From Android: "Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled. Other shared files should be placed in one of the directories returned by".

Comment: @Zelig63 Please submit an answer and I will pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)`, you will be able to retrieve which external directory exist on your device. You will then be able to check if "storage/emulated/0" appears in the list.